# ie8 breaking float:left into 2 rows

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

http://demo.jashwant.com/derek/

I have 'float:left' in `.navicon`.

**Expected behaviour:** All icons (next to logo) should be in same row (works in ff, chrome, safari)

But for reasons unknown, 5th and 6th icons are on another row in ie8/

p.s. I have tried `clearing` it, and `overflow:hidden` and setting `width` explicitly on container `#bloguin_navpanel` without luck.

I cannont reproduce the problem, so linking the website itself.

Comment: what is the build version of IE8?

Comment: @A.K How can I check that ? btw my ie has version: 8.0.7600.16385 64bit edition.

Comment: Have you experimented with removing the 5px of padding from #bloguin_football-nav .main-nav-tab?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes floats are not perfect across all browsers. And since you're using images for your nav, then the browser may prematurely render the toolbar before the images are loaded causing some of the successive images to wrap onto another row.

To get around this:

1. Set the #bloguin_navpanel as `float:left`.
2. Then set each item inside (`.navicon`) as `display:inline-block` (remove the float).
3. Finally, set your #bloguin_mainnav to `overflow:auto`.

Also, remove all the duplicate width and height stuff from any other the inner children of `.navicon`.

Comment: I've tried this too.

`display:inline-block` distorts it even badly.

Comment: OK then make a `display:table-cell;` for (#bloguin_logo, #bloguin_navpanel, #bloguin_socialpanel, #bloguin_newsletter) and set the parent element (#bloguin_innerpanel) to `display:table; width:980px; margin:0 auto;`